# Confused with something looking like the curiously recursive template pattern

Tags: c#, templates, generics, inheritance, crtp

I have an application made of several "levels" of elements. Some elements are parent of 0..N children elements, themselves being parent of 0..N other elements. The top level type has no parent and the bottom level elements have no children.

In other words, let three types : A, B and C. An instance of A is the parent of multiple instances of B, themselves being the parents of multiple instances of C. Each instance also has a (strongly typed) reference to its parent.

I have several methods that are the same in parent classes, like AddChild, RemoveChild, GetChildIndex, etc. I would like to have a base class for all parent classes in order not to duplicate these methods for each parent type.

The idea is that, when deriving from the parent base class, you have to provide the type of children, itself depending on the type of the parent.

So far I have come up with this overly complex design :

```
public interface IChild<TParent> where TParent : ParentBase<IChild<TParent>>
{
    TParent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentBase<TChild> where TChild : IChild<ParentBase<TChild>>
{
    public List<TChild> Children;
}

public class A : ParentBase<B>
{
}

public class B : ParentBase<C>, IChild<A>
{
}

public class C : IChild<B>
{
}
```

But I'm getting compile errors :

```
Error   CS0311  The type 'TemplateTest.IChild<TParent>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TChild' in the generic type or method 'ParentBase<TChild>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TemplateTest.IChild<TParent>' to 'TemplateTest.IChild<TemplateTest.ParentBase<TemplateTest.IChild<TParent>>>'.    Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 6   Active
Error   CS0311  The type 'TemplateTest.ParentBase<TChild>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TParent' in the generic type or method 'IChild<TParent>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TemplateTest.ParentBase<TChild>' to 'TemplateTest.ParentBase<TemplateTest.IChild<TemplateTest.ParentBase<TChild>>>'. Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 11  Active
Error   CS0311  The type 'TemplateTest.B' cannot be used as type parameter 'TChild' in the generic type or method 'ParentBase<TChild>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TemplateTest.B' to 'TemplateTest.IChild<TemplateTest.ParentBase<TemplateTest.B>>'.  Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 16  Active
Error   CS0311  The type 'TemplateTest.C' cannot be used as type parameter 'TChild' in the generic type or method 'ParentBase<TChild>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TemplateTest.C' to 'TemplateTest.IChild<TemplateTest.ParentBase<TemplateTest.C>>'.  Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 20  Active
Error   CS1721  Class 'B' cannot have multiple base classes: 'ParentBase<C>' and 'IChild<A>'    Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 20  Active
Error   CS0311  The type 'TemplateTest.B' cannot be used as type parameter 'TParent' in the generic type or method 'IChild<TParent>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TemplateTest.B' to 'TemplateTest.ParentBase<TemplateTest.IChild<TemplateTest.B>>'.    Kbd2    C:\dev\Kbd2\TemplateTest.cs 24  Active
```

I'm not even sure whether this can compile or not since classes depend on each other. Am I doing something wrong ? Thank you.

***EDIT*** : Added unimplemented methods and updated error list.

***EDIT*** : Simplified the example by making the child interface a base class instead of an interface, just like the parent class.

***EDIT*** : Actually only one base class is allowed so I turned the child type back into an interface instead of a class.

***EDIT*** : If I remove either of the two "where" constraints, the errors are all gone. Is it because they depend on each other ?

Comment: You've tagged this both template and c#? C# has generics not templates. Also you say an instance of A is a parent of multiple instances of B - how can that happen?

Comment: Obviously, this cannot works because the definitions are mutually recursive (and get more complex on each iteration). So you must remove one contraint or replace it by one that is not recursive.

Comment: @Phil1970 Thanks for your help. In the end i'll just drop this design and go for something else. If there can be only half of it there is not point. I'm curious though. Why isn't the compiler explicitely telling me that there is a circular dependency instead of these errors ? Is it because they simply did not cover this case of error ?

Comment: @ROX Yes that's what I meant, generics. I'm coming from a C++ background. Does it really matter anyway ? A can be a parent of multiple B instances because B is passed as the Child template parameter of ParentBase<> indicating the type of the children.

Comment: Yes, it does matters generics vs templates as they works very differently an C++/CLI support both of them. So you have to understand their differences if you have to write both kinds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that it relies on some kind of strange recursion. It's like saying:

- a child is a person with a parent
- and that parent is a person with a child that has a parent
- and that child is a person with a parent that has a child which has a parent
- ... this doesn't work!

If you think again about it, the parent/child relationship involves two types:

```
public interface IChild<P, C> where P : IParent<P, C> where C : IChild<P, C> {
    P Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface IParent<P, C> where P : IParent<P, C> where C : IChild<P, C> {
    IList<C> Children { get; }
}
```

While this may work, it looks very complicated, because in `IParent` the type paremeter `P` is not used and in `IChild` the type parameter `C` is not used.

But I think we're on the right track. If you simplify the interfaces and add the generic constraint to `ParentBase`, you get something more understandable:

```
public interface IChild<P> {
    P Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface IParent<C> {
    IList<C> Children { get; }
}

public class ParentBase<P, C> : IParent<C> where C : IChild<P>  {
    public IList<C> Children { get; } = new List<C>();
}
```

With this design, you have [separated concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

- an interface for parents
- an interface for children
- and a base class implementation

Your example works:

```
public class A : ParentBase<A, B> {
}

public class B : ParentBase<B, C>, IChild<A> {
    public A Parent { get; set; }
}

public class C : IChild<B> {
    public B Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void Test() {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B() { Parent = a };
        var c = new C() { Parent = b };
        a.Children.Add(b);
        b.Children.Add(c);
        System.Console.WriteLine(c.Parent.Parent == a);
    }
}
```

There are minor other details to note:

- for published lists, its common to use the interface `IList<T>` to abstract from the implementation
- public fields (like `children` in `ParentBase`) are uncommon, most people use a read-only property to encapsulate the list itself